# Redirect to thank you page

Tags: php, jquery

I've a contact form and its working well. But I want when visitors will send me message then page will be redirect to 'thank you page'.

here is my form's code:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "my-contact@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
    $from_email     = "noreply@your-domain.com"; //From email address (eg: no-reply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com)

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ;

    ### Attachment Preparation ###
    $file_attached = false;
    if(isset($_FILES['file_attach'])) //check uploaded file
    {
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['file_attach']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['file_attach']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['file_attach']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['file_attach']['error'];

        //exit script and output error if we encounter any
        if($file_error>0)
        {
            $mymsg = array( 
            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
            4=>"No file was uploaded", 
            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 

            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
            die($output); 
        }

        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
        $file_attached = true;
    }

    if($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
    {
        # Mail headers should work with most clients
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ".$from_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $message_body."\r\n\r\n";

        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."--\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type:  ".$file_type."; ";
        $headers .= "name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
        $headers .= "filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
        $headers .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
        $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."--";
    }else{
        //proceed with PHP email.
        $headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    }

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: are you using ajax to submit form?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your PHP vars and your tagging of jQuery I assume you are using jQuery POST.

Change your success or done to

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data.text) $("#messageDiv").html(data.text);

  if (data.type=="message" && data.text.indexOf("Thank you") !=-1) {
    location.replace("thanks.html");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi mplungjan, Thanks for your answer. can you please tell me where I'll put those code that you wrote above? I told before I've no good idea in php. If you tel me where I replace your code that will be very helpful for me.

Comment: You do not set it in the PHP at all. You change your jQuery AJAX call. If you can post the html and jQuery you have now I can insert it for you